# Moving code from Visual Basic to C++ issue

Tags: c++, vb.net

I'm facing an issue regarding the translation in C++ of a bunch of source code written in Visual Basic. In the code there is a call to the method Sign (VB) and various conversions of float to integer... Could you confirm that c++ code for 1, 2, 3 are the same as the VB one? In addition about the implicit conversion I've no idea how the conversion is performed (See 4). Any idea?

1) Method **Sign** (Visual Basic)

```
//C++
int sign(float value)   
{ 
    if (value < 0) return -1; 
    else if (value == 0) return 0; 
    else return 1; 
}
```

2) Method **Int** (Visual Basic)

```
//C++
int Int(float value) 
{ 
    return ((value >= 0) ? value : floor(value)); 
}
```

3) Method **CInt** (Visual Basic)

```
//C++
int CInt(const float val) 
{ 
    float x = fabs(val - (int)val);

    if (fabs(x - 0.5) < 0.0001) 
            return (int)val; 
    else 
            return (int)(val+(val>=0.0?0.5:-0.5)); 
}
```

4) And there is also an implicit conversion of double to int. How to make this conversion in c++?

```
//Visual basic
Dim dt As Integer = -99.2
```

Thanks you in advance,

Comment: Well, no, VB generates overflow exceptions.  Write tests, compare results until you're happy.

Answer (score 0):

1-
It is not the same, floating point values should not be compared to a constant variable (0, in this example). So, this is a better code for it:

```
const float epsilon = 0.00001f;

if(value < -epsilon) return -1;
if(value > epsilon) return 1;
return 0;
```

2- It depends on what you want for, for example -5.7. If you want -5, just cast away using (int). for example, if you have a float variable named f, use (int)f. If you want -6, use this function:

```
int Int(float value) 
{ 
    return ((value >= 0) ? (int)value : (int)(value-1)); 
}
```

3- It should work but last return statement could be made clearer:

```
return (int)val + (val>=0.0?1:-1)
```

4- Doubles are very very similar to floats in C/C++. Do as if you're messing with a float, not double.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I do not know if I've been clear but I would like that my methods written in c++ has exactly the same behavior of Visual Basic's method. And I'm not sure about the behavior of Visual Basic methods. It seems that Cint is a bankers rounding.